# Selection Sort Swap Count

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array including user's inputs. The program is about Bubble sort, Selection sort and Insertion sort. I couldn't manage to solve a problem in Selection part. Swap counter always gives me Array's length - 1. I know It's because of the first for loop but I couldn't find any solutions though.

```
int SComparison = 0;
int SSwaps = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < SorBag.length - 1; i++) {
        min = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < SorBag.length; j++) {
            SComparison++;

            if (SorBag[j] < SorBag[min]) {
                min = j;

            }
        }

        SSwaps++;
        temp2 = SorBag[i];
        SorBag[i] = SorBag[min];
        SorBag[min] = temp2;
    }
```

I tried putting SSwaps into "if", It gives me always 0. I tried making an "if" to find how many array elements are smaller than this first ones. Still the same. Where should put SSwaps++ ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

check this code :

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int SComparison = 0;
         int SSwaps = 0;
         int totalSwap=0;
        int min = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int SorBag[] = { 1, 4, 3 };

        for (int i = 0; i < SorBag.length - 1; i++) {
            min = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < SorBag.length; j++) {
                SComparison++;

                if (SorBag[j] < SorBag[min]) {
                    min = j;
                    temp = SorBag[i];
                    SorBag[i] = SorBag[min];
                    SorBag[min] = temp;
                    SSwaps++;
                    totalSwap+=SSwaps;
                    System.out.println("swap count at "+j+" pass : "+SSwaps);
                }
            }
            SSwaps=0;


        }
        for (int i = 0; i < SorBag.length; i++) 
            System.out.print(SorBag[i]+" ");

        System.out.println("\nTotal swap count :"+totalSwap);
    }


}
```

output :

```
swap count at 2 pass : 1
1 3 4 
Total swap count :1
```

Comment: Still same, when I make array's elements 1,2,3,4 ; It gives me 3.

Comment: This code gives me always 0. Bubble sort working well but I really have issues here...

Answer (score 0):

selection sort updates the min **index** by comparison (your `if ...`), and do the element swapping **if it is needed**.

You put the `swapps++` at right position. but you should check , if `min == i`. You only want to do swap if `min !=i`. instead, you didn't check that, just swap anyway. that's why you got fixed `length -1`

P.S. please try to follow the java naming convention.

Comment: I moved SSwaps++ into if ( min != i ). But now the output is always 0. I also tried this BTW but didn't work as well.

Comment: @HalilM then the input is already sorted. Assuming your sorting logic works properly.

Comment: @HalilM and the first `for` should be : `i < SorBag.length`

Comment: Well when I try 33 21 7 25, It gives 0. I also deleted - 1. But again 0 :/.

Comment: if ( min != i ){
            SSwaps++;}
            
            temp2 = SorBag[i];
            SorBag[i] = SorBag[min];
            SorBag[min] = temp2;   I only moved SSwaps++ into if.

Comment: @HalilM either you printed wrong var or your array was already sorted. I run your codes, the `SSwaps` gave expected value. btw, those swapping codes should go into the `if(min!=i){...}` block too, but this doesn't influence the `SSwaps` value.

Comment: I'm sure your code is right but I really don't know why mine isn't working... My Bubble sorting works fine and Its counter is inside an "if".

Comment: BTW I debugged the code, It never gets in the "if". Which is interesting. I think that's why It doesn't count.

Comment: I got the problem you won't believe :). Bubble sort is making the array sorted that's why It doesn't count. Amazing. I maked 2 other temp arrays and equaled them at first. But It's still the same :/

Answer (score 0):

Whats the issue?
With your code this gives 4 swaps which is correct.

```
    int[] SorBag = new int[]{5 ,4 ,3 ,2 ,1};
    int min = 0;
    int SComparison = 0;
    int SSwaps = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SorBag.length - 1; i++) {
            min = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < SorBag.length; j++) {
                SComparison++;

                if (SorBag[j] < SorBag[min]) {
                    min = j;
                    SSwaps++;
                }
            }


            int temp2 = SorBag[i];
            SorBag[i] = SorBag[min];
            SorBag[min] = temp2;
        }
    System.out.println("sswaps : "+SSwaps);

    for(int i = 0; i<5;i++){
        System.out.println("SorBag["+i+"] = "+SorBag[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making it 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. It gives 4 also.